# Android Como crear elemento de interfaz que ocupe toda la pantalla

Tags: android

Imaginemos que tengo una aplicación vacía recién creada de tipo **"Navigation Drawer Activity"** luego en el diseño agrego un webView siguiente mente lo extiendo en toda la pantalla y el problema es el siguiente en el cual no ocupa la  pantalla completa

**¿Existe alguna manera que mi webView pueda ocupar toda la pantalla?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La manera que una vista ocupe toda la pantalla hasta el día de hoy no es posible, lo que te recomiendo es [esconder la barra de estatus](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html)

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
  }else{
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        // Hide the status bar.
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
        // Remember that you should never show the action bar if the
        // status bar is hidden, so hide that too if necessary.
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
       actionBar.hide();

 }
```

y configurar las propiedades a tu vista:

```
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

de esta forma se vería la vista, "full screen":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]